# Reading h.246 NAL header info

Tags: hex, h.264, codec

Looking for more detailed info on how to read the NAL header and more specifically the SPS (sequence parameter set) NAL unit.

Here are two examples:

- 00000001674d401fba202833f3c200000300c800002ed5c0400249e0002dc6f451807c60c4480000000168ebef20
- 0000000127640028ac721005005bb01100000303e90000ea60e000002b7cc00006cb80ef7b80f84422890000000128ebef2c

Any details or in-depth explanations on how to read this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to convert your NAL from EBSP to RBSP, after that you can use reference provided by Bob

eg
00 00 03 -> 00 00

Answer (score 1):

H.264 video is specified in ISO 14496 part 10.

The 000001 is an annex B start code.  Next will be the nal_unit() specified in section 7.3.1.  Inside the NAL is the rbsp for the SPS or PPS.

The syntax of seq_parameter_set_rbsp() is specified in section 7.3.2.1 .

pic_parameter_set_rbsp() is specified in section 7.3.2.2.